# If a PC summons creatures to help fight does it lower your party’s XP?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, experience-points, summoning

Do summoned creatures take a share of the XP of an encounter? Let’s say a PC in a party of 3 uses a spell like Conjure Animals. He uses it to summon all 8 creatures. If they contribute to the combat, is the XP split by 3 or is it split by 11?

Answer (score 15):

Summoned creatures do not gain XP. [As @Mindwin said in an answer to a different question:](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105381/12193)

> They are part of a class feature of the character, and considered as "part" of that character. They are not NPC, they are creatures under the control of the PC with strict guidelines.

If a player summons additional help to aid the fight, they are using their own abilities to do so. Usually, in these cases that is what they are *meant* to do. A Druid or a Ranger don't have particularly high combat abilities, compared to other classes like the Fighter or the Barbarian, so they instead summon help, to assist.

They are using their skills to aid the fight, therefore they gain the experience for doing so, not the animals for making the kills.

Comment: "A druid doesn't have particularly high combat abilities" I would **not** say that :P other than that, both this answer and Mindwin's answer (to the linked question) would be improved by textual evidence from the books. While both are correct, right now it feels like "because I said so."

Comment: Umm, rangers have a higher damage output then fighters do (up to 10th level, after 5th level they never really increase how much damage they can do). Also rangers don't really get summoning dorks in 5e

Comment: I think this answer, while right, could be clearer. It's correct that **summoned creatures do not gain xp** - but that necessarily doesn't mean the same thing as **summoned creatures don't lower your parties xp** (which is what's being asked about). For instance, NPC's can't *normally* gain XP but can still lower the parties xp.

Comment: 1) when quoting another answer you should make that clear so people don't mistake it for a rules quote (I have fixed that for you, feel free to tweak it if it doesn't fit right). 2) That answer doesn't have a lot of consensus (votes) behind it so I'm not sure that quoting it is even very helpful. I second the notion that this answer needs more textual support and logic to actually answer the question.