# How are tamed animals treated in terms of abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, animal-companions, animals

In a campaign I am playing in the DM allows the taming of wild animals, but you have to devote time and resources to training them to follow commands after the initial taming.

Would these animals, after the training, just have the basic stats for that creature, or would they get the same special abilities over time as a beast master ranger's or druid's animal companion?

For example in my current situations I tamed an owl, so would it just use the owl statblock or would it get the abilitys of a beast master ranger or druids animal companion of being able to take class levels and all the other stuff that goes with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for owning and training animals?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59291/what-are-the-rules-for-owning-and-training-animals)

Comment: not really. the dm has already decided that we can use animal handling to tame wild animals, but im wondering if it would get the special features the a beast master rangers animal companion has or if it would just use the basic statblock after taming it and training it to follow commands,

Comment: This does not need to be closed. None of the answers are opinion based and they show the question can be answered without opinions.

Comment: Note that druids don't have "animal companions" in 5e to begin with. Also, I'm not sure what you're referring to by "abilities" here, given that there are no player-facing default/core rules that allow a non-PC creature to be "able to take class levels" - for the Beast Master ranger's animal companion or any other non-PC. Could you edit the question to clarify what particular "abilities" you think the animal might gain from this process (and perhaps why you think a Beast Master ranger's animal companion have the "ability to take class levels")?

Comment: I don't think the question's necessarily opinion-based, but I'm having trouble understanding the reasoning behind the claims being made within it. (It's possible to answer the underlying question even if those particular misconceptions are corrected, but I'm curious where those misconceptions are coming from - e.g. from past editions.)

Comment: @V2Blast when I was researching if there was rules on this I saw that there was a spell druids could get that essentially gave them a beast master rangers animal companion, which I had been told was able to take levels in certain classes as well as having other special features that other animals don't have. Its possible that since I wasn't specifically researching those features that it was from an older version or was homebrew since I didn't look too far into exactly what the features were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## This is a house rule and needs your DM to tell you

Unfortunately, there aren't specific rules about training animals and how specifically it works, what they can do, or how it may change their stat blocks.

Your DM is allowing this and will need to let you know how it works.

### Some guidance for your DM

Action economy is incredibly important in 5e. I'd be wary to add more combatants as that is going to skew the encounters. If they are allowed, as it seems they are, I would not give them the full blocks and abilities that Druids or Beast Rangers get. That steps on the toes of those classes.

Your DM is also going to need to figure out who is in control of the beast and how they're going to act/react. The simplest is that the player gets to do that, but remember that this is a beast and still has it's own mind. A DM may, at times, take agency over you for control of the animal if it makes narrative sense.

Technically, these may also be considered NPCs and may require a share of XP. [They can't actually use the XP, just take it away from your shares](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115273/what-do-npcs-do-with-gained-xp), but they can/may detract from the actual party's XP total as well. This can be seen as a bit of a balancing factor for adding to the action economy.

[Steve's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178155/23024) also brings in the new optional rule from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything about sidekicks which could be another option to consider.

Answer (score 4):

### Your DM could, optionally, include the sidekick rules from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*

*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* includes a new optional section about [sidekicks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/dungeon-masters-tools#Sidekicks) (p. 142), NPCs that join your group and aid you in your quests. This may not strictly adhere to how you and your DM envisioned trained animals working but it offers guidelines. As it is optional, your DM is free to use or ignore at their discretion.

From the rules on sidekicks:

> A sidekick can be incorporated into a group at the party’s inception,
> or a sidekick might join them during the campaign. For example, the
> characters might meet a villager, an animal, or another creature,
> forge a friendship, and invite the creature to join them on their
> adventures.
>
> [...]
>
> A sidekick can be any type of creature with a stat block in the
> *Monster Manual* or another D&D book, but the challenge rating in
> its stat block must be 1/2 or lower. You take that stat block and add to
> it, as explained in the “Gaining a Sidekick Class” section.
>
> To join the adventurers, the sidekick must be the friend of at least
> one of them. This friendship might be connected to a character’s
> backstory or to events that have transpired in play. For example, a
> sidekick could be a childhood friend or pet, or it might be a creature
> the adventurers saved. As DM, you determine whether there is
> sufficient trust established for the creature to join the group.

The rest of the chapter goes into what type of sidekick you have (its class basically) and how it levels with the party.

As an optional extra, it is still very DM-dependent, but it may give you some ideas on how exactly a trained animal might work in your campaign.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ask your DM.

You wrote:

> the dm allows the taming of wild animals, but you have to devote time and resources to training them to follow commands after the initial taming.

So it is up to the DM to tell you what this looks like and how to use it.