# How do I deal with all the NPCs in Out of the Abyss?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, out-of-the-abyss

Most combat tips were to either give them to players or make a background scene where they would be fighting. But how do I keep track of the progression of the living NPC and loot share, etc?

Comment: Are the suggestions in the beginning of the module not adequate?

Comment: Slightly related: [In Out of the Abyss, do the NPCs get a full share of XP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101887/35259)

Comment: Also, this question is a little lacking on detail, would you be able to expand on what exactly is causing you a problem? Maybe give an example?

Comment: For example, what do you mean by "how do I keep track of the progression of the living NPC"?

Comment: @BlakeSteel: No answers or partial answers are allowed in the comments. Answer material should be placed in answers below. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Out of the Abyss, do the NPCs get a full share of XP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101887/in-out-of-the-abyss-do-the-npcs-get-a-full-share-of-xp)

Comment: I agree with NathanS's comment, and hope you add some detail on what's troubling you. I also find many (for me "many" = ">2") tough to deal with, and feel like having the concrete example of OotA will help ground this question in a way that a more-general "how do I productively portray many NPCs" couldn't. Thanks for the good question!